# ubuntu 18.04.4 lts wired connection is missing

Tags: internet, wired, pppoe

I have plugged in wire in my laptop but no wired connection is appearing in "Network" Section.

I tried following instructions in this article

> This tutorial is going to show you how to set PPPoE connection in
>   Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS using Terminal.
>
> Using Terminal commands
>
> Open up your terminal and type the following command to set your PPPoE
>   connection.
>
> nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name “YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME” Now enter
>   your DSL account and password provided by your ISP and save your
>   settings in the following command.
>
> set pppoe.username YOUR_DSL_ACCOUNT_USERNAME set pppoe.password
>   YOUR_DSL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD save Then it will prompt asking Saving the
>   connection with ‘autoconnect=yes’. That might result in immediate
>   activation of the connection. Do you still want to save? (yes/no).
>   Type yes and quit.

Still, there is no wired connection section.

[image]

Comment: Please run _sudo rfkill list && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3_ and highlight the resulting text. Copy the text as text, come back here, click [edit], and paste the text into your question so we can see which LAN adapter your (unspecified) PC has.